# Why Titanic than Titanik, Why Cat but not Kat

Tags: pronunciation

Why in English language we write something and read something else.

In my mother tongue Malayalam and National Language Hindi , we read what we write as such.

But that is not the case of English.

Like

Titanic  - to me Titanik seems more apt than Titanic

Kat seems more apt than cat.

Why English is so much confusing. it is taking me forever to learn the pronunciation.

Comment: Because that's the way we do it. And you won't get a better explanation than that.

Comment: Short answer: Because a first-century Roman rhetorician named Quintilian hated the letter K.

Comment: It is really funny to realize that most pronunciation learned from school is very different from the real thing.

Comment: Anyone looking to learn English pronunciations can use "phonics" websites. Phonics Play's page at www.phonicsplay.co.uk/WhatIsPhonics.htm explains what phonics is. Websites such as http://www.phonicsplay.co.uk have been set up to allow school children to learn how to read and pronounce the words.

Comment: You think it would be better to use _Titanik_? You'll be hard pressed to find many other English words that end with -ik – there are [very few](http://onelook.com/?w=*ik&scwo=1&sswo=0) – but [plenty that end with -ic](http://onelook.com/?w=*ic&scwo=1&sswo=0) (in fact, there are [thousands](http://onelook.com/?w=*ic&scwo=1&first=1401) of those). It's not just about the phonetics and sounds, but combinations that have etymological roots. It's tricky, but not quite as random as it many seem.

Comment: You might like this - http://www.ashvital.freeservers.com/ze_dream.htm

Comment: @Drossel This is very interesting. I was hoping for someone to take the initiative.

Comment: It is a 20-years-old joke :)

Comment: @Drossel Thats fine. but when going through it, after reading for  a while, seems more sensible, other than the double letter though

Comment: @Drossel No one needs to hold a pronunciation dictionary in a hand to read English. I think, if someone knows how to pronounce the letters , they should be able to read.

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan - English pronunciation and spelling are notoriously tricky, and just knowing the sounds of the letters is not enough.  Consider *comb, bomb*, and *tomb*, which are all spelled very similarly but are pronounced differently.  Or *cough, although*, and *through*.  In *ball* and *ballerina*, the first syllable is spelled the same but pronounced differently.  Why is *hyperbole* pronounced very differently from either *hyperactive* or *bole*?  Et cetera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, one letter may have many different pronunciations.  If you hear a word, there is no way to know, just from the sound of the word, how to spell it.  However, a written word will frequently have only one way you can say it.  The words "goatee" and "ghoti" for instance would both be pronounced the same way, and even though "ghoti" is not actually a real English word, we know how it sounds just from how it is written.  (see: http://zompist.com/spell.html for more details on this)

The ability to spell the same SOUND in many different ways is useful, because there are many words that sound the same, but have different meanings.  "There" and "Their" is one famous example.  Even though these sound exactly alike, it is useful to have different spellings for them, because the meaning is very different.

Spellings can also give you information about the "root" of the word, or its origin, or even its history.  English borrows words from other languages very often, and we typically like to keep the original spelling from the original language, even though our spelling rules may be different.  Over time, the way people say words can also change, but we usually keep the spelling the same.  (For example, the word "Knight" used to be pronounced "Kh'ni'git", which is more or less how it is spelled, but when we changed how the word sounded, we did not change how to spell it)

Spelling can also inform you about the grammatical function of the word.  To use your example, "Titanic", this word comes from the word "Titan" and the suffix "-ic", which makes the noun into an adjective.  This "-ic" ending, however, can only be used with words that come from certain languages, specifically Latin or Greek.  So by seeing that the word ends in "-ic", we know that the word comes from Latin or Greek, and is an adjective.  Knowing that the word comes from Latin or Greek is important because the origin of the word tells us a lot about how formal the word is.  For instance, Latin or Greek words are much more formal than German words.

Sometimes there is no real reason for one letter to be used over another, but once a letter was picked, it just stays that way forever.

Comment: I know it's an old joke, by G B Shaw, but it may be amusing to note that **ghoti** could be pronounced **fish**. gh = /f/ as in enough. o = /i/ as in women. ti= /sh/ as in nation

Comment: What do you mean by "Kh'ni'git"? *Knight* was never pronounced with a hard G or with that epenthetic vowel. The historical pronunciation was /knɪxt/, [knɪçt], similar to the German cognate *Knecht*.

Comment: The "ghoti" thing is a pet peeve of mine.  I get the joke, but gh- at the *beginning* of an English word is never pronounced *f*.  (As zompist points out!)  Consider ghoul, ghost, ghetto.